# Is there any way to stop Teams blinking it’s taskbar icon?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've tried the solution [here](https://www.technipages.com/microsoft-teams-how-to-disable-blinking-in-taskbar)

but it still doesn't work.  I've turned off all the notifications I can in Teams.  Every time something happens in Teams - it could be something I have *zero interest in*, or something I can perfectly well attend to when I take a break and check email etc - that Teams taskbar icon starts flashing.

It's making it impossible to get any work done.  Am I going to have to just put a piece of gaffer tape over the screen?

Comment: I went ahead and removed the mask profanity from your question title.